# Random Forest Fine-tuning stuck in running

Tags: python, random-forest

```
rf_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(class_weight = "balanced",
                                       random_state=7)
param_grid = {'n_estimators': [50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175],
              'min_samples_split':[2,4,6,8,10],
              'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 3, 4],
              'max_depth': [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]}

grid_obj = GridSearchCV(rf_classifier,
                        iid=True,
                        return_train_score=True,
                        param_grid=param_grid,
                        scoring='roc_auc',
                        cv=10)

grid_fit = grid_obj.fit(X_train, y_train)
rf_opt = grid_fit.best_estimator_

print('='*20)
print("best params: " + str(grid_obj.best_estimator_))
print("best params: " + str(grid_obj.best_params_))
print('best score:', grid_obj.best_score_)
print('='*20)
```

Fine-tuning the random forest algorithm's hyper-parameters by cross-validation against the AUC score. The above code is just stuck loading in my jupyter notebook. Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you tried passing `verbose=3` to increase the verbosity of the output? This should tell you whether the code is still running (if you see some output) or there's something wrong.

Comment: Just tried passing verbose = 3 and it's still stuck loading, no output.